# ASP.NET MVC 4 - How to write complex custom url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, seo, custom-url

Dynamic url of one of my page is as given bellow:

"http://myDomain/CarComparison/CompareCarTab?brandIds=3~3~3&modelIds=8~8~7&modelVersionIds=4~5~19"

Here **CarComparison** is **controller** and **CompareCarTab** is **action**.

**4~5~19 represent car version name**.

Now please guide me how i can customize above url as given bellow.

"http://myDomain/Car-Comparison-Hyundai-i20-Magna-VS-Hyundai-i20-Magna-Optional-1.2-VS-Hyundai-i10-D-lite"

**Here  "Hyundai-i20-Magna-VS-Hyundai-i20-Magna-Optional-1.2-VS-Hyundai-i10-D-lite" part is denepdent on "modelVersionIds=4~5~19"**

Thanks,

@Paul

Answer (score 0):

For starters you're going to need to create a new route in your RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "",
    url: "comparison/{cars}",
    defaults: new { controller = "carcomparison", action = "carcomparetab" }
);

// /comparison/car1-vs-car2-vs-car3
```

And I don't know how you can convert that type of url `Hyundai-i20-Magna-VS-Hyundai-i20-Magna-Optional-1.2-VS-Hyundai-i10-D-lite` into some usable parameter other than splitting it on `VS` and looking each up by name in your database.

---

Another possibility would be to have multiple routes for comparing

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "",
    url: "comparison/{car1}/{car2}/{car3}",
    defaults: new { controller = "carcomparison", action = "carcomparetab" }
);

// /comparision/car1/car2/car3
```